# How to log errors in try/catch statement laravel?

Tags: php, logging, error-handling, try-catch, laravel-5

Im performing a try catch statement where I need the code to do something and if it fails catch the error, log it to the laravel log file and continue with the loop. My code is:

```
    foreach ($logins as $login) {
        try {
            // Do something here
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // Log errors
            \Log::error( $e->getMessage() );
            continue;
        }
    }
```

But I am getting an error that reads

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]                           
Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement in the script
```

I've used \Log:: in the name space and also tried adding the `use Log;` but I still get this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one of the scripts, there is a namespace declaration similar to this:

```
namespace projects\name;
```

The error is triggered because there is some other script line before the declaration. That's illegal: namespace declaration must be the first execution statement.

Once you fix that, then this line:

```
\Log::error(...)
```

Will also cause you an error. A leading `\` means that you're accessing a class in the global PHP namespace. If your `Log` class is in a specific namespace, for example `projects\name`, then you can use the class in one of two ways. Using a fully qualified name:

```
\projects\name\Log::error(...)
```

Or using a `use` statement.

```
use projects\name\Log; //early in the file. No need for leading \
...
Log::error(...)
```

Comment: Thanks that was my issue. Also had to add a \ for `\Exception $e` as laravel is namespaced.

Comment: Log is a facade in the root (global) namespace for Laravel.